# Why can't I index a SUBST'd drive in Windows7?

Tags: windows-7, subst

I've got a SUBST for a folder to drive letter P:

I have noticed that exploring these folders from P: is now INCREDIBLY slow, taking up to a minute sometimes to show files. I'm showing them as general files and not thumbnails, so it's not that.

Looking at the original folder in explorer is lightning fast.

I've checked the indexing options and indeed the folder where my files are stored is checked as indexed. I can see my P: drive in the list, but clicking on the checkbox won't do anything. It's not even checkable.

Does anyone have any clues as to how I can fix this?

(Running Windows 7 just to be clear).

Answer (score 1):

Map a drive to a path, just like on network share, but locally. By NET command or in explorer.

Comment: In explorer you can map drive to a local folder by, for example, \\localhost\c$\Windows.

Comment: Did't help, some folders are loading for ages. AFAIK, NET is based on SUBST.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Control Panel / Indexing Options, to see all the currently indexed locations.

Click the Modify button and a screen will come up that, if P is listed, will allow you to specify
the P drive as indexed by clicking on the check-box. Then click OK.

To have effect, this requires a reboot and may take some time.

Comment: Yes, this worked, thanks. On Windows 8 a reboot isn't required. However, Andy said that the relevant check-box is disabled for some reason, hence, this can't be considered as a complete answer to the original question.

P.S. I will award the bounty in one hour.

Comment: @OlegsJeremejevs: Do you mean that Windows 8 doesn't agree to index subst drives ?

Comment: No, in my case it worked just fine (actually, I enabled indexing yesterday, but since I can't cancel bounty I decided to wait for a proper answer). I pointed out, that question author's problem is a bit different.

Comment: If Andy doesn't come up and describe better his problem it can be anything : my above answer, slow browsing or even search service stopped.